# Only do "OR" if first match didn't exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Part of my MySQL query looks like this:

```
LEFT JOIN edu_experience e ON e.exp_user = u.user_id 
AND e.exp_current = '1'
OR e.exp_user = u.user_id 
AND e.exp_start = e1.MaxExpStart 
AND e.exp_type != '0'
```

However, I only want to do the "OR"-statement if the: `e.exp_user = u.user_id AND e.exp_current = '1'` didn't match.

So, if I simply do this query - it works:

```
LEFT JOIN edu_experience e ON e.exp_user = u.user_id 
AND e.exp_current = '1'
```

But not in all scenarios, why I need the "OR" statement.

Comment: If your first clause returns true, it matches, and if the first clause returns false and the second returns true, it matches as well. So where's your problem?

Comment: I don't think you understand. If there is any row in edu_experience, where exp_current equals 1, then the OR should be simply skipped (because, the OR will then select a row, based on other consumptions). So: if exp_current = 1, dont do the OR.

Comment: Is e1.MaxExpStart the result of MAX((table e with another name).exp_start)?  If so, can you give upper and lower bounds on the values in exp_start?

Comment: I'm sorry, your requirements are still not very clear. Please provide a *complete* example including input and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
LEFT JOIN edu_experience e ON (
  e.exp_user = u.user_id 
  AND (
    e.exp_current = '1'
    OR e.exp_user = u.user_id
  )
  AND e.exp_start = e1.MaxExpStart 
  AND e.exp_type != '0'
)
```